# I can't get jQuery to embed in my page

Tags: jquery, html

I'm on the very first step of learning jQuery (I'm already somewhat familiar with JavaScript), but I can't seem to get the jQuery file to embed into my index.html page. I'm learning that "jQuery" is a variable which appears valid in HTML *only* if jQuery is embedded into the page, so I've made the following code to test if the jQuery is linked:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Learning JavaScript</title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<script="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>


<body>
<script>

    if (typeof jQuery !="undefined") {
        alert('jQuery is installed!');
    } else {
        alert('jQuery is NOT installed!');
    }

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Of course, I want an alert to appear which says "jQuery is installed!" but I'm getting the "jQuery is NOT installed" alert because of the else statement. In other words, the variable "jQuery" is showing up as "undefined." As you can see from my code, I'm linking to a file that's in my folder, but you can also link to jQuery's url, which is found here: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js  Either way, I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: for one: <script="text/javascript" is invalid. should be <script type="text/javascript"

Comment: I recommend to follow the [**jQuery tutorial**](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/) and have a close look at the code/markup.

Comment: Can you see the file being loaded in the Network tab in the dev tools in the browser? The problem is in loading the file. The check itself is right.

Comment: Wow, amateur mistake! Thank you for catching that.

Comment: I'd turn that into an answer for you to accept but I think this question should just be deleted. You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure `jquery.min.js` is right in the same place as your `index.html`-- you probably already got that
2. I see that you wrote `<script="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>` when you should probably have written `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>` instead
3. You could also try linking directly to the jquery source and see if that solves things

So this should work for you:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Learning JavaScript</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <!-- it has to be <script type=""> not <script=""> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- or you could try this: -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

</head>


<body>

<script>
    // this should work...
    if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
        alert ('jQuery is installed!');
    } else {
        alert ('jQuery is NOT installed!');
    }

    // but this is more idiomatic:
    // this will run on page load
    $(function () {
        alert('jQuery is installed!');
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```